# wxWidgets: make tooltips less annoying,

Tags: c++, tooltip, wxwidgets

I have added tooltips to my checkbox elements, but they are too annoying. They appear immediately after hovering the mouse cursor over the element and do not disappear after the cursor has left the checkbox.

I could start a timer, but I don't know how I can check if the cursor is within the desired element or has left it.

And the second question is, is there any event like `wxEVT_LEAVE_WINDOW`, but for the checkbox to remove the tooltip when the cursor goes out of bounds.

Comment: I actually don't see a way to remove a rich tool tip when the mouse leaves the window.  Are you sure the standard [tooltip](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tool_tip.html) class can't work for you?  It behaves in the way you want by default.

Comment: I've been having the same problem with rich tool tip. There is no event that I know of to detect whether the mouse leaves it, furthermore according to the manual " ... is not derived from wxWindow ". You might want to take a look at transient popup window: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_popup_transient_window.html#ad9a80da9627d9412570f73fa4d047512

Comment: As it turned out, the tooltip disappeared, but after 3 seconds after moving the mouse pointer. And I found something: wxRichToolTip has a `SetTimeout()` method that does exactly what I want it to do.

But now I get the error `MyApp.exe has triggered a breakpoint.` in appbase.cpp in the `wxDefaultAssertHandler` function. It says `// can't use assert here to avoid infinite loops, so just trap`.

Comment: Apparently the error appears due to the fact that when processing the event, I create a window tooltip several times. I could set the boolean variable and not create new tooltips, but I need to reset this variable when the window disappears. Do you know a way to know when the tooltip is disappearing?

Comment: Looking over the source, there doesn't seem to be a way to manually dismiss the tooltip or receive an event when it dismisses itself.  So if you need this, I think you'll have to create your own tooltip class and add these features based on the existing rich tool top class.   I don't see an easier way.

Comment: It is very strange. If I have to create my own tooltip class in order to get quite standard behavior, then I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I think I found a really hacky way to do this.  Internally, the rich tool tip creates a wxPopupTransientWindow, so after calling `ShowFor(window)`, you can iterate over window's children and find the popup window.  You can then attach an event handler for `wxEVT_DESTROY` to that popup to get a notification of when the tooltip is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @New Pagodi
I am still dont get normal behaivor of tips, but your trich works. I can get tip window from wxCheckBox element just calling `GetChildren()`.

```
wxRichToolTip* tip = new wxRichToolTip(wxT("INFO"), msg);
tip->SetTimeout(0, 500);
tip->ShowFor(it->second.first);
wxWindowList tipWindow = it->second.first->GetChildren();

auto a = tipWindow.GetLast()->GetData();
a->Bind(wxEVT_MOTION, &DeviceListDialog::onLeaveCheckbox, this);
```